# How to get ISO FriendlyName when mount it

Tags: powershell

I was able to get the drive letter of ISO by using this code:

```
$driveL= (Mount-DiskImage $OriISO -PassThru | Get-Volume).DriveLetter
```

When I'm trying to get the ISO name and store in a variable, it doesn't show any result when I echo it. I think I actually retrieve the name of ISO as I get this error message "Maximum 32 volume label" when I use that variable. I can't use that same ISO volume label in my own created ISO, am I doing something wrong? Please let me know.

Code Im using to retrieve ISO name:

```
$script:isodrive = (Mount-DiskImage $OriISO -PassThru | Get-Volume).FriendlyName
```

Comment: Sorry Im using phone to post this question. Feel free to edit my question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Ansgar Wiechers for helping to edit my question. Appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very, very close to the answer.

```
PS> $dvd = 'C:\Source\en_office_professional_plus_2019_x86_x64_dvd_7ea28c99.iso'
PS> $vol = Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath $dvd -PassThru | Get-Volume

PS> $vol.DriveLetter
E
PS> $vol.FileSystemLabel
16.0.10730.20102
```

The actual property is FileSysetmLabel.  FriendlyName as shown in the Get-Volume output is an alias created in the CDXML module and also created for output in the formatting system

use
PS> $vol | Format-List *
to view all of the properties

Comment: When i run mount it shows FriendlyName so I thought it was. Thanks for your explanation and answer.